# Does this qualify as a statement?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

Is this a statement?

> All positive integers with negative squares are prime.

What do we need to qualify as such?

Comment: What are your thoughts, what is a statement?

Comment: @Bob R The *proper* definition of statement is most likely beyond what is intended in the course. I guess you just need to intuitively make sure that that sentence actually asserts something and it's not just a bundle of words.

Comment: A statement that has a true or falseness? Clearly its false, (number)^(-2) != prime always.

Comment: @BobR Did you men to say "a sentence" in the above comment? If so, that's probably the way you're supposed to think about it.

Comment: yes, A a statement is a sentence**

Comment: If you know about quantifiers, you might want to know that that sentence can be formalized as $$(\forall n\in \Bbb Z^+)(n^2<0\implies n\in \Bbb P)$$ where $\Bbb P$ denotes the set of all prime numbers.

Comment: @BobR: The statement is actually true. You've read it incorrectly. As Git Gud has written formally, it says that all positive integers whose squares are negative are primes. And since the antecedent is false, the statement is automatically true, because the only way that "If A then B" is false is if it is possible that A is true and B is false.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is a statement. It may sound absurd, but it is a statement, and it happens to be *vacuously* true.

However, a statement **doesn't have to be true**: logically, a statement, sometimes called a proposition, is an assertion that can be assessed as either **true**, **or else false**, and cannot be *both* true and false. We do not necessarily need to know at a given point in time exactly ***what*** its truth value is, but it simply needs to be such that it is true or else false.

**Examples of non-statements:**

- How are you?
- Do your homework!

ADDED: see [**vacuous truth**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

> A vacuous truth is a truth that is devoid of content because it asserts something about all members of a class that is empty or because it says “If A then B” when in fact A is inherently false.

Comment: Another example of a non-statement:
I robot pee )$x\to $ bollocks.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to make sense of the sentence rather than if its a statement or not.

Comment: @BobR Do you understand what the statement says now?

Comment: Yes, it may not make sense, because there are no positive integers whose square is negative, so the implication can never be false. It is stating **IF** such integers existed, then all such integers would be prime. Since NO such integers exist, any conclusion can follow. That's why I said it is "vacuously true", but a statement nonetheless.

Comment: This is similar to a statement of the form: if $x \in \varnothing$ then $x = \pi$.  Since the empty set has not elements, there is no way the statement can be false. I.e., it is *vacuously true*. It doesn't tell us much at all. But by default, it is true. An implication $p \implies q$ is **TRUE whenever** $p$ is false, no matter what. It is also true whenever we have $q$ = true.

Comment: @GitGud I like that non-statement.  Also I find it amusing that under the informal definition of "statement" mentioned by others, "all positive integers with negative squares are prime or I robot pee $)x \to$ bollocks" qualifies as a statement.

Comment: I hope you are is a peaceful colored sleep, my dear friend Amy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A statement needs to have the property of being true or false.  "The best integers are prime" is not a statement, but an opinion.  The one in OP is indeed a statement, and is also true.

Comment: Is the continuum hypothesis a statement? It seems to be. Is it true or is it false? We can't tell. Is it either true or false? That's problematic!

Comment: @John, the continuum hypothesis has the property of being true or false.  True in some models of set theory, false in others.